# Jackson Json String generation not working

Tags: json, scala, serialization, jackson

I am trying to use Jackson to generate json string from scala objects.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper 
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule

trait Base
case class A(s: String) extends Base
case class B(s: String) extends Base
case class Result(a: Option[Base], b: Option[Base])

object App {

  val jsonMapper =
    new ObjectMapper()
      .registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)

  def main(args : Array[String]) {
    val x = Result(Some(A("a")), Some(B("b")))
    println(jsonMapper.writeValueAsString(x))
  } 
}
```

I am expecting an output like this

```
{"a":{"s": "a"},"b":{"s": "b"}}
```

but what I get is this,

```
{"a":{},"b":{}}
```

Maven dependency that I am using is,

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-module-scala_2.9.2</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Let me know if I am missing something here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you should define generic type for `Result`:

```
case class Result[T <: Base](a: Option[T], b: Option[T])
```

Comment: Awesome this works. Thanks. Its strange, because I was using jerkson (which uses older version of jackson) and it worked fine. But when I moved to ObjectMapper for jackson 2.2.2, I started having this issue. Any idea why your solution works?

Comment: Sorry but I can't understand this behavior too.. And digging into sources don't give me answer for now..

Comment: No problem, I will do with your solution now.